# Xorg configuration to switch between ttys (FreeBSD)

Tags: vmware, xorg, freebsd, xorg.conf

I'm using FreeBSD on VMWare.
I'm installing/configuring Xorg. To get a .conf file I used

```
Xorg -configure
```

I tested it with

```
Xorg -config /root/xorg.conf.new -retro
```

It seemed to be okay, so I copied the generated file into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.
I'm now trying to switch from a tty to another, but here's the problem: it seems like it's impossible. I'm stuck into the graphic mode.

Do I have to add some lines in the .conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer: the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-8]</kbd> combo is caught by VMWare because of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>: it's one of VMWare shortcuts (focus on VMWare window). So the guestOS can't catch it to switch to another.

[**<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> key combinations in a virtual machine console**](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1011705)